Where can I find data about Vancouver's elevation slope?
Where can I find (or create) something like an elevation map, but instead of elevation, it would be change in height (i.e. slope/steepness)?
I'm trying to find steep, but not too steep locations for physical training. I'm only interested in freely-available data for Metro Vancouver.
I did find some elevation data with grid area map (with Vancouver being 92G) and the corresponding DEM data, but several of the grid panels are missing (linked dataset for 92G only has 01 to 16, with 17 to 100 missing).
I don't know how to map the slope to the location/street name either. Calculating and visually plotting the slope from this can be done in ArcGIS/QGIS.

Don't know any specific highways dataset which has the slope attribute in. But having DTM + highways it can be calculated. Below an example in R.
First of all, we have to get elevation data from your source and unzip the files:
if(!dir.exists("data/vanc")) { dir.create("data/vanc")}
base_url <- "https://pub.data.gov.bc.ca/datasets/175624/92g/"
download.file(url = base_url,
              method = "wget",
              extra = "-c -np",
              destfile = "data/vanc/index.html")

l <- xml2::read_html("data/vanc/index.html") |>
  xml2::xml_find_all(xpath = "//a") |>
  xml2::xml_attr(attr = "href")

l <- l[which(!grepl("md5", l) & grepl("zip", l))]
l <- paste0(base_url, l)

for(i in seq_along(l)) {
  if(!file.exists(paste0("data/vanc/", sub(".zip", "", basename(l[i]))))) {
    download.file(url = l[i], 
                  destfile = paste0("data/vanc/", basename(l[i])),
                  method = "wget",
                  extra = "-c")
    unzip(paste0("data/vanc/", basename(l[i])), exdir = "data/vanc/")
    
  } else {
    message("File already downloaded")
  }
}

Then read raster files in and merge:
l <- list.files(path = "data/vanc",
                pattern = ".dem$",
                full.names = TRUE)

r <- lapply(l, terra::rast)
r <- do.call(terra::merge, r)
terra::plot(r)


Half of the job done. Now we have to find some highways in Vancouver. In below example we will use OpenStreetMap data (with osmdata package), limited to North Vancouver:
bb <- osmdata::getbb("North Vancouver, Canada")
h <- osmdata::opq(bbox = bb, timeout = 30*60) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "highway") |>
  osmdata::osmdata_sf()

highways <- h$osm_lines |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = terra::crs(r))

Content of highways:

highways[, c("osm_id", "name")]
#> Simple feature collection with 4779 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -123.1168 ymin: 49.29874 xmax: -123.0309 ymax: 49.33994
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
#> First 10 features:
#>            osm_id              name                       geometry
#> 4934808   4934808      Mahon Avenue LINESTRING (-123.0863 49.31...
#> 4934809   4934809   West 6th Street LINESTRING (-123.0808 49.31...
#> 4935053   4935053   West 4th Street LINESTRING (-123.0824 49.31...
[...]

Now we have to calculate "slope" of highway. Please note, OSM data can be fragmented, ie. it will have the whole highway geometry, however it might be divided into several linestrings (fragments). Nevertheless, we will calculate slope of each fragment. To calculate the "slope" of highway fragment we will find start and end points, its length and calculate the slope as arcus tangent of height difference and length (in degrees).
highway_metric <- function(highway) {
  start_point <-  sf::st_geometry(highway) |>
    sfext::as_startpoint() |>
    terra::vect()
  
  stop_point <- sf::st_geometry(highway) |>
    sfext::as_endpoint() |>
    terra::vect()
  start_point
  start_point_height <- terra::extract(r, start_point)[[2]]
  end_point_height <- terra::extract(r, stop_point)[[2]]
  
  length <- units::drop_units(sf::st_length(highway))
  
  highway_slope <- atan(abs(end_point_height - start_point_height)/length)*180/pi
  return(highway_slope)
}

Now we are adding additional column to our highways with slope:
highways <- highways[, c("osm_id", "name")] |>
  dplyr::rowwise() |>
  dplyr::mutate(slope = highway_metric(geometry))

highways |>
  subset(slope >= 5 & !is.na(name)) |>
  dplyr::arrange(dplyr::desc(slope)) |>
  sf::st_drop_geometry() |>
  head(10)
  
# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Rowwise: 
   osm_id     name              slope
   <chr>      <chr>             <dbl>
 1 336151736  Spirit Trail       33.2
 2 341926212  Spirit Trail       31.8
 3 1199693600 Queensbury Avenue  25.1
 4 1041803694 Spirit Trail       19.6
 5 1193065782 Tempe Crescent     19.0
 6 1132138652 Spirit Trail       15.1
 7 1054894995 Spirit Trail       14.6
 8 1057989202 East Keith Road    14.1
 9 508134093  East 27th Street   12.5
10 106147360  Spirit Trail       12.4

And finally let's plot those where slope > 5:
terrain <- terra::terrain(r, v = c("slope", "aspect"), unit = "radians")
dtm_hillshade <- terra::shade(slope = terrain$slope, aspect = terrain$aspect)

terra::ext(highways) |>
  terra::plot()
terra::plot(dtm_hillshade, 
            col = gray(0:30 / 30), 
            add =TRUE,
            legend = FALSE
)

highways |>
  subset(slope >= 5) |>
  dplyr::arrange(dplyr::desc(slope)) |>
  terra::plot(col = "white", add = TRUE)


Created on 2024-10-07 with reprex v2.1.0

Not sure where highways came in (I didn't mention anything about highways in my post). The first image doesn't seem to resemble anything about the geography of Vancouver. The second image doesn't seem to resemble the slope of North Vancouver land. Am I misunderstanding something?

Yes, you are right, you mentioned "location/street name" not highways. Highway is another (technical in OSM) name for street/road/trunk/path. In above example you got a recipe how to map "slope" to any highway (street name). The first image shows whole DTM provided by you, Vancouver itself sits on plato around -123W, 49.15N. The second one is just a snippet for North Vancouver. You may repeat the steps for yourself, play with Vancouver areas, replace highways with other "street names" dataset etc. Please check https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/terrain.html as well.
